# Writing the objective function and constraints for scipy.optimize.minimize from matrices

Tags: python, scipy, roc

I'm trying to find the optimal threshold point from a ROC curve. I have two main constraints : tpr >=80 and fpr <=60. I tried three main minimization functions :

```
#where, tpr=True positive rate and fpr = false +ve rate 

dis= math.sqrt(math.pow((1-arr[1]), 2) + math.pow((0-arr[0]), 2))
dis= math.pow((1-arr[1]), 2) - math.pow((0-arr[0]), 2)
dis= -1*math.sqrt(math.pow((1-arr[1]), 2) + math.pow((0-arr[0]), 2))
```

My first function assumes that the point with least distance from best point (1, 0) while meeting my constraints is the optimal point. Is that a correct way to think ?

I find the point (0.84558824, 0.58104396) to be more optimal as it gives me better tpr with a higher fpr within my constraints but my function returns a value of x = 0.53708791, y = 0.80147059 as the optimal point.

[image]

I then tried weighting the trp by a factor of 6. The reason for this is that I want to weight the "tpr" more than "fpr". This gave me (0.84558824, 0.58104396) which I think is the best point.
dis = math.sqrt(((math.pow((0-arr[1]), 2))) + (6 * math.pow((1-arr[0]), 2)))

The new graph :
[image]

There was a 3rd approach I tried, where I took, 1`*math.sqrt(math.pow((1-arr[1]), 2) + math.pow((0-arr[0]), 2))`, since I want to distance between `1 & tpr` to be low, but that between 0 and fpr to be small. ie, the best point lies left most & upward.
**What is a more mathematical way to approach the problem ?** I also saw the minimize function with ability to specify constraints with bounds, but I am unable to formulate the problem . The three possibility for the mathematical formulation above, all look intuitive, but give different results wrt to the optimal point.

To put things together, I used a pseudo heuristic as here

```
def min_fun(arr):
     dis = math.sqrt(((math.pow((0-arr[0]), 2))) + (6 * math.pow((1-arr[1]), 2)))
     if arr[1] > 0.80 and arr[0] < 0.60:
          return dis
      else:
           #return max distance for ROC graph if conditions not met.
           return math.sqrt(2)
#and then, just appending the list of minimum distances (candidate set), to get the best point later 
a_list = zip(fpr,tpr,thresholds)
distances = []
for s in a_list:
    distances.append(min_fun(s))
threshold_index = distances.index(min(distances))
threshold  =a_list[threshold_index][2]
```

I know grid search/DP/Scipy minimize are the right candiadtes here - to which, how do I frame this problem rigorously ?

Related -

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148296/python-minimize-function-passing-additional-arguments-to-constraint-dictonary?rq=1
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476152/dynamically-writing-the-objective-function-and-constraints-for-scipy-optimize-mi

Comment: Unless the issue is specific to python 2.7, please consider tagging the question simply python instead.

Comment: The optimal point depends very much on your application. In mass spec proteomics we usually use a hard 1% FDR because we want very little crap in our positive results, other applications want to get as many good examples as possible, so they use higher thresholds. Anyway, this question would be better suited for CrossValidated.